# How to redeploy host-manager webapp on Tomcat 7?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I have Tomcat 7 installed on Ubuntu 12.04, and I installed the package tomcat7-admin, which gave me two webapps: manager and host-manager. Then in the manager I accidentally undeployed the host-manager, and I can't seem to bring it back. I looked in the `CATALINA_BASE/webapps`, neither of the webapps is there. Reinstalling the package tomcat7-admin didn't do anything.

What should I do to bring back the host-manager webapp? There has to be some simple solution which I can't see myself.

Comment: The host-manager is located /usr/share/tomcat7-admin/host-manager. I guess you can simply copy & paste the directory in the webapps directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try reinstalling all of Tomcat or simply download the latest ZIP file from  http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi/ and copy `webapps/host-manager` to your existing Tomcat webapps dir.

**UPD**

Ubuntu 10.04 includes Tomcat 6 but I'm guessing Tomcat 7 is implemented in the same way.

The host-manager is installed in `/usr/share/tomcat6-admin/host-manager` which is referenced by `/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml`. In there, I find:

```
<Context path="/host-manager"
    docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6-admin/host-manager"
    antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" />
```

Comment: I think the webapp is still there, it is just not deployed. I was thinking myself about deploying manually, but it is deployed in some tricky way, it is not in the webapps folder. manager is working fine from somewhere, not from webapps, host-manager was probably deployed the same way. Reinstalling everything would probably help, but that's a lot of work, I was hoping for something simpler than that.

Comment: @Malcom, Please see update

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-docs tomcat7-admin
```

Will install the manager app, which is missing if you only did

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```